# Use token for Windows Server 2008 AD RMS

Tags: windows, active-directory, drm

I have a Windows Server 2008 configured for AD RMS (Active Directory Rights Management Service), another Windows Server 2008 machine that is the domain controller, and a third machine that is a member of the domain I've created to be a client.

How can I use a token in this scenario to provide access to every document with credentials on it in the client machine?

Comment: Is the question that you want to protect all the documents on a computer with RMS?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the token to authenticate the user to the machine.  RMS uses a client certificate granted by the windows authenticated user to access the RMS protected document.